# Get last array object where key is lower than $i? PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm trying to grab the last object inside an array where the key is lower than $i in a for loop.

The reason for this is because the array key is unix time, and I need to grab the element that is closest to the current time which in my case is $i.

How can you achieve this in PHP or laravel?

Basicially the reason for this is because I am making a chart and I am adding missed dates between the array containing the dates where we have data.

And for every missing date it should use the date before current dates data.

I hope it make sense.

Edit 1:

What I've tried to use is laravels array_first helper:

```
$first = array_first($array, function ($value, $key) use ($i) {
    return $key <= $i;
});
```

But this did not work.
I also tried phps end() function which gets the last object in the array, however this did not work either.

Here is the code for the whole function:

```
public function getPortfolioHistory($days, $currency, $type)
{
  if(count($this->getHoldingLogs()) > 0)
  {

   //$history = Cache::remember('1213:'.$this->id, 1440, function() use ($days, $currency){
  $logs = $this->getHoldingLogs(); // Get all logs
  $fromdate = strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays($days)); // Gets the last day it should get prices from
  $array = array(); // Array that handles dates
  $token = array(); // Array that handles token amounts for calculations
  $cmc_id = array(); //Array that handles coinmarketcap ids
  $pricelog = array(); //Array that handles coinmarketcap historical prices
  $paid_usd = 0;

  foreach($logs as $log)
  {

    // This block checks if the holdinglogs date is older than the fromdate, it should set its date to the $fromdate (starting date)
    if(strtotime($log->date) < $fromdate)
    {
      $log->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $fromdate);
    }

    // Just a variable for resetting $worth_usd for each $log
    $worth_usd = 0;
    $paid_usd = 0;
    // Reformat the date
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($log->date));

    // Checks if this token has been set or not in the $token array, if it has been set we update its amount.
    if(!isSet($token[$log->token]))
    {
      $token[$log->token] = array('token' => $log->token, 'amount' => $log->amount, 'cmc_id' => $log->token_cmc_id, 'paid' => $log->paid_usd);
    } else {
      if($log->paid_usd == 0 && $log->amount < 0)
      {
        $log->paid_usd = 0 - (($token[$log->token]['paid'] / $token[$log->token]['amount']) * (abs($log->amount)));
        $log->save();
      }
      $token[$log->token] = array('token' => $log->token, 'amount' => $token[$log->token]['amount'] + $log->amount, 'cmc_id' => $log->token_cmc_id, 'paid' => $token[$log->token]['paid'] + $log->paid_usd);
    }


    // Since we need to recalculate using the amounts each day, we loop through the tokens in $token
    foreach($token as $key => $coin)
    {

      // This checks if we have already read in the price array for this token, if it has not been set we get it.
      if(!isSet($pricelog[$coin['cmc_id']]) && $coin['cmc_id'] != "FIAT")
      {
        $pricelog[$coin['cmc_id']] = $this->getHistorical($coin['cmc_id']);
      }

      // If the token is a fiat we set its price to 1 and then we multiply the amount * price * fiat later in the code.
      if($coin['cmc_id'] != "FIAT")
      {
        $price = $this->returnPrice($pricelog[$coin['cmc_id']], $log->date);
      } else {
        $price = 1;
      }

      // Here we calculate the worth.
      if($coin['cmc_id'] != "FIAT")
      {
        $worth_usd += $coin['amount'] * $price['USD'];
      } else {
        if($key == "USD")
        {
          $worth_usd += $coin['amount'];
        } else {
          $worth_usd += $coin['amount'] / (1 / Multiplier::where('currency', $coin['token'])->select('price')->first()->price); // If its a fiat and its not USD we convert it to usd.
        }
      }
      $paid_usd += $coin['paid'];
    }

    // Sets the record in the array with all the needed data.
    $array = array_set($array, strtotime($date), array('worth_usd' => $worth_usd, 'tokens' => $token, 'date' => $date, 'paid' => $paid_usd, 'generated' => "no"));
  }



  // Sort the array by key.
  ksort($array);

  // This is the method depixel wrote to add missing dates.
  for($i = key($array); $i <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); $i += 86400)
  {

    if(isSet($array[$i]) == false)
    {
      // This gets the record before $i, so we can read in the latest holdings.
      $latest = end($array);

      echo date('Y-m-d', $i) . " - " . $latest['date'] . "<br>";

      // Set worth_usd to 0.
      $worth_usd = 0;
      $paid_usd = 0;

      // Formats the $i unix time to a suitable date.
      $missingdate = date('Y-m-d', $i);

      foreach($latest['tokens'] as $key => $coin)
      {

      if(!isSet($pricelog[$coin['cmc_id']]) && $coin['cmc_id'] != "FIAT")
      {
        $pricelog[$coin['cmc_id']] = $this->getHistorical($coin['cmc_id']);
      }
      if($coin['cmc_id'] != "FIAT")
      {
        $price = $this->returnPrice($pricelog[$coin['cmc_id']], $missingdate);
      } else {
        $price = 1;
      }

      // Worth of this holding this day
      if($coin['cmc_id'] != "FIAT")
      {
        $worth_usd += $coin['amount'] * $price['USD'];
      } else {
        if($key == "USD")
        {
          $worth_usd += $coin['amount'];
        } else {
          $worth_usd += $coin['amount'] / (1 / Multiplier::where('currency', $coin['token'])->select('price')->first()->price);
        }
      }
      $paid_usd += $coin['paid'];

    }
    if($missingdate != date('Y-m-d'))
    {
      $array = array_set($array, $i, array('worth_usd' => $worth_usd, 'tokens' => $token, 'date' => $missingdate, 'paid' => $paid_usd, 'generated' => 'yes'));
    }
    }
  }
  // Sort array by time
  ksort($array);
  // Print it out
  $history = $array;
//  });

  echo "<pre>";
  echo var_dump($history);
  echo "</pre>";

  foreach($history as $worth)
  {
    if($type == "Value")
    {
      echo $worth['worth_usd'].", ";
    } else {
      echo $worth['worth_usd'] - $worth['paid'],", ";
    }
  }
}
}
```

EDIT 3:

I actually solved it by using this:

```
      $latest = null;
      foreach ($array as $key => $date) {
         if ($latest === null || $key < $i && $key > key($latest)) {
            $latest = $date;
         }
      }
```

However if anyone has a better way to do it please let me know.

Comment: Can you provide at least the code that you've tried?

Comment: @dextereb I've tried multiple different approches but neither worked for me, hence looking for help here, I'll edit the post with some more info and the array structure

Comment: Post one example of what you've tried, don't just tell us about your "multiple" approaches

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Updated OP with tested code and also the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

(Sidenote: Your solution actually doesn't work, because it has a massive bug in it: `key($latest)` means "get the value of the key at the current index of the array called `$latest`" -- but `$latest` is not the array you're searching through, nor does it know the key in `$array` that it came from.)

It's great that you're sorting `$array`, but there's an important benefit that gives you that you're missing out on: the ability to do a binary search.

Unfortunately, since your array keys are not consecutive and zero-based (i.e. actual indexes), binary search would be a bit difficult. So I would change this line (by the way, your use of `array_set()` here is completely unnecessary):

```
$array = array_set($array, strtotime($date), array('worth_usd' => $worth_usd, 'tokens' => $token, 'date' => $date, 'paid' => $paid_usd, 'generated' => "no"));
```

to this:

```
$array[] = ['date' => $date, 'time' => strtotime($date), 'worth_usd' => $worth_usd, 'tokens' => $token, 'paid' => $paid_usd, 'generated' => 'no'];
```

Now your array keys are merely indexes, so you can do a binary search to find the index of the most recent entry before the current date:

```
$lbound = 0;
$rbound = count($array) - 1;
$current_time = time(); // or whatever timestamp you're looking for

while($rbound - $lbound > 1) {
    $midpoint = $lbound + ($rbound - $lbound) / 2;

    if ($array[$midpoint]['time'] <= $current_time) {
        $lbound = $midpoint;
        continue;
    }
    $rbound = $midpoint;
}

if ($array[$lbound]['time'] === $current_time) {
    $lbound--;
}
// Now $lbound is the index of the most recent entry before the current time
// -- unless the first element in the array is the current time, in which
// case $lbound will be -1, which would represent failure or "not found".
// However, even in that case, the insertion point for the new entry
// would still be $lbound + 1.

// So you would insert a new entry like this:
//     array_splice($array, $lbound + 1, 0, [$new_entry]);
// don't forget the [ ] around that array variable!
```

Haven't tested that code so hopefully it's right. The only caveat is that this code won't work on an array of only two elements (but you don't even need binary search on something that small).

[edit]
If you need to account for a 2-element array, you could use the following code instead, although it's not quite as performant due to the additional `if`:

```
$lbound = $midpoint = 0;
$rbound = count($array) - 1;
$current_time = time(); // or whatever timestamp you're looking for

while($lbound <= $rbound) {
    $midpoint = $lbound + ($rbound - $lbound) / 2;

    if ($array[$midpoint]['time'] === $current_time) {
        break;
    }
    if ($array[$midpoint]['time'] < $current_time) {
        $lbound = $midpoint + 1;
        continue;
    }
    $rbound = $midpoint - 1;
}

if ($array[$midpoint]['time'] >= $current_time) {
    $midpoint--;
}

// and in this case, $midpoint will hold the position of the most recent
// entry before the current time -- unless the first element in the array
// is the current time, in which case $midpoint will be -1, which would
// represent failure or "not found".
// However, even in that case, the insertion point for the new entry
// would still be $midpoint + 1.

// So you would insert a new entry like this:
//     array_splice($array, $midpoint + 1, 0, [$new_entry]);
// don't forget the [ ] around that array variable!
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I will take this all into account. I'm really grateful for it, I've been developing for about 1 year and I learn new stuff every day. Thank you. I will take this all into account, I am actually using this for our my website which has a userbase of 30k, so any improvements is game changing. 
Anyway, how would you do it if the array only has two elements? I am thinking because sometimes I am sure the array will only have 2 or less results. (for example if the $logs date is today)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the algorithm that can handle a 2-element array. I've also tested both algorithms on paper and they do seem to work properly.